# jQuery: Contains Vs Equals

Tags: jquery, html, telerik

I'm actually certain this has been asked (somewhere) before, but I just can't seem to get a 'normal' answer one way or another.

I am trying to use the telerik tab control, and selecting to open a tab depending on a clicked link's text.
General Layout of page:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|      HEADER                            |
+----------------------------------------+
| N  |+--------------------------------+ |
| A  ||    Tabstrip                    | |
| V  ||                                | |
| B  ||                                | |
| A  ||                                | |
| R  ||                                | |
|    ||                                | |
|    ||                                | |
|    |+--------------------------------+ |
+----+-----------------------------------+
```

I.e. my nav could look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|     HEADER                   
|                        
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
| Users                  |    __________    __________    ___________
+------------------------+   /  Users   \  / Products \  / Suppliers \
| Products               |  /            \/____________\/_____________\_______________
+------------------------+ |
| Suppliers              | | Tab content here for users page
+------------------------+ |
| Orders                 | |
+------------------------+ |
| Stock                  | |
+------------------------+ |
```

So, By clicking on an item within the navbar, I wish to make the corresponding tab become active.

My Nav items are created with something similar to:

```
<li id="users">    <a href="#">Users      </a></li>
<li id="products"> <a href="#">Products   </a></li>
<li id="suppliers"><a href="#">Suppliers  </a></li>
<li id="orders">   <a href="#">Orders     </a></li>
<li id="stock">    <a href="#">Stock      </a></li>
```

I then have a tab control (which is auto-generated), and The Page inspector at runtime shows

[image]

which is the actual tab controls. They are made through this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("tabMain")
  .Animation(true)

  .Items(items =>
      {
        /*index 0 */  items.Add().Encoded(false).ImageUrl("~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png").Text("Users&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp").Content(Html.Action("Index", "User").ToString());
        /*index 1 */  items.Add().Encoded(false).ImageUrl("~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png").Text("Products   &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp").Content(Html.Action("Index", "Products).ToString());
        /*index 2 */  items.Add().Encoded(false).ImageUrl("~/Content/Images/CLOSE.png").Text("Suppliers&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp").Content(Html.Action("Index", "Suppliers").ToString());
        /*index 3 */  items.Add().Encoded(false).Text("Orders").Content(Html.Action("Index", "Orders").ToString());
        /*index 4 */  items.Add().Encoded(false).Text("Stock").Visible(false).Content(Html.Action("Index", "Stock").ToString());

      })
 )
```

## The Actual Question

I want to be able to press a button on the navbar and it display the specified tab/make it active.

So, enough background, i'm currently using the jquery:

```
 $('#stock').click(function(e){
            //alert("Stock is what was pressed");
            $('#tabMain-1').toggle(); //simply used for testing purposes
            $("");
 });
```

to try and select the corresponding tab.

What should my selector be to get the unique tab id/index/aria-controls (with value - this seems to be their version of 'unique id for the controls)? Should I be using ":Equals" or ":Contains"?

Or should I be using something different altogether to select this tab title name thing?

Html, As requested:

Comment: where did `#stock` suddenly come from?

Comment: sorry, I didn't show all links in navbar. Will add now

Comment: Can you provide HTML, shown on the screenshot? Also, based on what should `<div>` be selected? On its index?

Comment: @Regent added (for what it's worth) - as for your last point I think i could get away with selecting this `k-item` if i could check if it has an `aria-controls` attribute as well as the attributes' value of `tabMain-...`

Comment: read this several times and it's very hard to make much sense out of what the objective is. What you posted as `html` is server code, not html.

Comment: It's what Kendo UI uses. As I said, it's auto generated. But will try and edit to make this clearer

Comment: @jbutler483 server-side code is indeed quite useless. I was talking about final rendered HTML in browser which is shown in screenshot. Nevertheless, this is how I see what is required: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/tcwtpp3o/).

Comment: @Regent my bad (as you can prob tell I'm not a web dev). here's a [link to the rendered html](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/fp1hbjq0/1/)

Comment: @jbutler483 [This is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/fp1hbjq0/2/) with fiddle fixes, but without kendo JS and CSS in external resources it simply doesn't work. By the way, what about fiddle with the idea of using `.index()`, that I provided?

Comment: @Regent I was actually lookingint that. And it was your comment *final rendered HTML in browser* which made it easier to see what was being added to the markup. Is there a way of targeting elements with that `aria-control`/`aria-content` thing?

Comment: @jbutler483 if you don't want to add to your fiddle related to `.kendoToolBar()` JS and CSS to allow to see final (after Kendo modified DOM) HTML - it's your choice. About targeting element by `aria-controls`: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/tcwtpp3o/1/).

Comment: So I should be looking to use this .attr instead?

Comment: @jbutler483 It looks so to me based on your screenshot. It might be that Kendo itself uses `aria-controls` to map `<li>` to `<div>`, so  you can do just the same. [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is pretty straightforward thing in this situation.

Comment: I didn't even know there was such a thing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one. I am not familiar with the Kendo controls, but based on your markup, I think the following code below might work. The code will only work if your nav items are in the exact same order as your tab items, ie: the code below uses index-based searching.

```
    $('.nav li').click(function(){

        //get the index of the nav item that was clicked
        var index = $('.nav li').index(this);

        //remove the active css class from all of the tabs
        $('.k-tabstrip-items .k-item').removeClass('k-state-active');

        //get the tab at the specific index
        var tabItem = $($('.k-tabstrip-items .k-item').get(index));

        //add the active css class to the tab
        tabItem.addClass('k-state-active');

        //get the tab id from the tab item
        var newTabId = tabItem.attr('aria-controls');

        //remove the active css class from all of the tab content divs
        $('.k-content')
            .removeClass('k-state-active')
            .attr('aria-expanded', false)
            .attr('aria-hidden', true);

        //add the active css and set the aria properties for the selected tab content div
        $('#' + newTabId)
            .addClass('k-state-active')
            .attr('aria-hidden', false)
            .attr('aria-expanded', true);

    });
```

Note: This code assumes your `<ul>` tag has a class of `nav`, ie: `<ul class="nav">`. If it doesn't, you'll need to change the javascript a little.

Comment: `$($('.k-tabstrip-items .k-item').get(index))` can simply be `$('.k-tabstrip-items .k-item').eq(index)`.

Comment: Nice! I did not know that.